# Entity Framework 6 Customising SQL with extension methods

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I've done quite a bit of searching, but I've not been able to find any decent sources of information to give me pointers in how to achieve what I want to do.

We're currently using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and I'm trying to write an extension method to add an expression to an IQueryable. I'll need to provide a custom implementation of the logic used to generate the sql for this, but I'm unsure how to do this.

I've seen I can use DbCommandInterceptors and the DbCommandTreeInterceptors to do various things, I'm not sure if they fit my requirements.

My ultimate aim to have something like:

```
var results = context.Table.MyMethod().Where(x => x > 10);
```

MyMethod will been an extension method within which I'll add my new expression:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> MyMethod<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source)
{
    // snipped
}
```

I then need to be able to handle this somewhere when the SQL is ultimately generated. I've seen an example in an [EntityFramework Core issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5845) which seems to do something along the lines of what I want, but I'm unsure if this is possible in EF6.

Apologies if this is a bit vague, but I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible.

**Update**

I've managed to work around what I need to do by setting a property on my context prior to invoking my query and then using the DbCommandInterceptor to replace some of the generated SQL (similar to what is done [here](http://codingsight.com/entity-framework-6-extensions-you-might-be-unaware-of/#modification)), but it doesn't *feel* like a great way of achieving what I want and seems hacky.

Another option I considered, which I'm not sure is possible, was to add something to the IQueryable (some sort of predicate or attribute) which I could then check for in a DbCommandTreeInterceptor.

From there I could then update some properties on the context, amend the generated DbQueryCommandTree to remove my custom attribute (so it doesn't break the SQL generation done by the SqlGenerator for Sql Server) and then do my SQL replacement in the DbCommandInterceptor as I do at present.

Comment: May be [this](https://github.com/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions) could help

Comment: Thanks for the link, but not quite what i'm after.